# How to troubleshoot my SQLite database in a PhoneGap application?

Tags: sqlite, mobile, cordova, lawnchair

I am using Phonegap and Lawnchair with the SQLitePlugin adapter (https://github.com/davibe/Phonegap-SQLitePlugin). How do I troubleshoot the DB to see what's happening? The DB doesn't seem to show up in the web inspector tool as a localstrorage would. How do I know if anything is happening with the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use phonegap build, you can use a debugger on you phone and have access to a console to run any javascript you need.

https://build.phonegap.com

Answer (score 0):

I use this free app:

Sqlite DB Browser
http://sqlitebrowser.org/

In the case you are using the ripple extension in Chrome you can then open the database located in:

> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\MY_USERNAME\Data\Default\databases\http_127.0.0.1_3000

The last folder depends on the url and the port you are accessing to your debugging app. Ex. **http_localhost_3000** or **http_127.0.0.1_3000**

Beware that the Sqlite database created by ripple file has no extension, and has a filename like **"6".**

With this app I managed to browse and check data on my database in realtime, if you **Insert or Edit** data using this app be sure in pressing the button **WRITE CHANGES**, because ifnot this will make you phonegap app to crash.